# graph - How to avoid reprocessing same edge twice in Depth First Search?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

The [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) describes BFS and DFS quite well. The code for dfs in the book has a problem when deciding whether or not to avoid double processing edges. I found the [Errata](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/algorist/book/errata) and applied the errata to the code, but still I think the refined code has a problem of checking double processing edges.

I paste the refined code as follows:

```
dfs(graph *g, int v) {
       edgenode *p;
       int y;
       if (finished) return;
       discovered[v] = TRUE;
       time = time + 1;
       entry_time[v] = time;
       process_vertex_early(v);
       p = g->edges[v];
       while (p != NULL) {
             /* temporary pointer */
             /* successor vertex */
             /* allow for search termination */
             y = p->y;
             if (discovered[y] == FALSE) {
                   parent[y] = v;
                   process_edge(v,y);
                   dfs(g,y);
             }
             else if (**(!processed[y] && parent[v] != y)** || (g->directed))
                   process_edge(v,y);
             if (finished) return;
             p = p->next;
       }
       process_vertex_late(v);
       time = time + 1;
       exit_time[v] = time;
       processed[v] = TRUE;
}
```

The place where I think there is a problem is marked via ** **.

So the questionable place is one of the conditions. Let's assume it is undirected graph, so we can just ignore the condition of `(g->directed)`.

Ok, let's focus on `parent[v] != y` first. if `parent[v] == y`, of course, we don't need to process edge v->y again because y->v is already processed once when processing vertex y.

And if `parent[v] != y`, my question is whether `!processed[y] &&` is necessary or not.

So, if y is not v's parent, and `processed[y] == false` which means y has been found (otherwise the execution can't reach `else if` part) but not been processed, so y must be a grandma or above of v. This is a back edge, but no problem, we can process it as it hasn't been processed yet.

Now what if `processed[y] == true`? **I think this "if" will never happen and this condition will never be true.**

Why? Ok, let's assume `processed[y]` can be true. This means that all paths which include y have been processed and also all vertexes in those paths have been processed, right? So if this is a case, how can a "not yet finished processing" vertex v approach y?

**I think in dfs, *no vertex will ever approach a processed vertex*, am I right?**

So if we never will meat a processed vertex, we can just remove `!processed[y]` as it will be always true.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `processed[y]` means all edges that could go out of `y` has been visited, right? In that case, no that can't happen. Maybe it was meant to be `&&`ed with `g->directed`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `processed[y] == true` could yield true.

Look at the following graph, and assume the following [feasible] DFS traversal:

```
v0,v1,v2
```

[image: graph example]

`v0` starts, and then recursively invoke `dfs(v1)` after processing `(v0,v1)`. Now, `v1` processes `(v1,v2)` and recursively invoke `dfs(v2)`. `v2` sees that `v0` is discovered and go to the `else if` statement, and sees that `(v0,v2)` was not processed and `parent[v2] != v0` [`v2` was discovered via `v1`].

Now, when we go back from the recursion we reach back `v0`, and when we check the next "son" - it is `v2`. `v2` was already discovered, so we go to `else if`, and `v2` is not the parent of `v0`, so without the `!processed[y]` part, we would have processed `(v0,v2)` twice.

The only thing that prevent that from hapenning is the fact that `processed[y] == true`

Comment: yeah, you are right, I ignored the fact that y might be a child of v