# All possible path in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, np, graph-traversal

Given a graph *G(V, E)*, a source vertex *s* and destination vertex *d*, the problem is to find all possible paths from *s* to *d* where *G* may contain loops and cycles. I want to get all simple paths, no cycle is allowed.

What would be the complexity of this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all paths on undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298423/find-all-paths-on-undirected-graph)

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Find all graph paths", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-hard, since its output may have an exponential size w.r.t its input.

Finding the [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) between two points is already NP-hard (reduction to hamiltonian path problem), so finding all of them is as well.

You can also see that this problem has an exponential complexity by seeing that there might be an exponential number of paths between two vertices in a graph.
Here is a small example:
Let `G` be a graph with `3n+2` vertices. Let `V = {s,d} U {a1, ..., an} U {b1, ..., bn} U {c1, ..., cn}` be its vertex set.
We build edges as follow:
-from `s` to `a1`
- for `i in 1...n`, we build an edge from `ai to bi`, from `ai to ci`
- for `i in 1..n-1`, we build an edge from `bi to ai+1`, from `ci to ai+1`.
- from `bn to d`, from `cn to d`.
As you can see, there are about `2^n` paths from `s` to `d`.