# All possible path in a directed pseudograph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, np, np-hard

Given a directed pseudograph G(V, E), a source vertex s and destination vertex d, the problem is to find all possible paths from vertex s to d where no cycle is allowed.

What would be the complexity of this problem? Is it NP?

Comment: Why do you think it would be NP? What research have you done on the topic? Why do you think the complexity of this problem would be any less than the complexity of the problem in your previous question?

Comment: I am looking for a proof saying this specific graph problem is NP.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't show the research that you've done or how you've tried to solve this problem. You don't even mention [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934990/all-possible-path-in-a-graph). Possibly the solution there could be extended to your current question. Please note that the first step in [ask] is "Search, and research..."

Comment: The previous problem was on a directed multigraph. But this problem is on a directed pseudograph. I have found solutions for finding all possible paths using DFS. But I am particularly looking for a complexity analysis for finding all possible paths from source to destination in a directed pseudograph (book/resource reference could be helpful).

Comment: can't we just transform the pseudograph to a directed one by weighting the edge (by how many edge of same source and same destination there are) and then perform the standard algorithm. Then instead of counting the paths, just summing each past cost?